# Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128'

Tags: php, laravel, localhost, mcrypt

I have successfully installed Laravel, but after running `php artisan serve` and going to `localhost:8000` I get this error:

> Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128'

I have checked `phpinfo()` on `localhost:8888` and it says that `mcrypt` is properly installed. However the only thing I can think of is that maybe my path is wrong?

in my `.bash_profile` I have

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Every time I try to run Laravel commands I have to type this in the terminal:

```
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

I am running on a Mac. Is there a simple way I can set up my `bash_profile` so that I can consistently change between localhost addresses and still have all the proper PHP functions working?

Comment: Have a look at your php.ini to see if the `mcrypt` extension is enabled. Remember you may have two PHP config files - one for the console and one for the web (that said, the Artisan `serve` command may in fact invoke the built-in PHP web server, which I suspect would use the console ini file, and not the Apache one). A good start would be to try `php -m` at your console and see if this extension is enabled.

Comment: `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` requires libmcrypt  2.4 or above. Verify you are meeting minimum requirements. Also see [Mcrypt ciphers](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php) in the manual.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

More simple way on ubuntu

- `apt-get install php5-mcrypt`
- `mv -i /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/`
- `php5enmod mcrypt`
- `service apache2 restart`

Note: if you don't have "/etc/php5/conf.d" just skip that step and it will work ok

check http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php

Comment: mv -i /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/ showing error.
"mv: cannot stat ‘/etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini’: No such file or directory". but ultimatily working . thanks

Answer (score 3):

This problem relative to the PHP extensions loader.
You no need to use laravel command at all after successful installation.
Laravel framework need Mcrypt Library for the security module and encrypt some of configure file.

The things that you need is theses steps.

1. Download Mcrypt http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrypt/files/Libmcrypt/2.5.8/libmcrypt-2.5.8.tar.gz/download

then configure make and install it.

2. Download php http://php.net/releases/index.php 
   Above 5.5.14 are suggested. (Use this path later on step 4)
3. then download Autoconfigure

   ```
   curl -O http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/autoconf-latest.tar.gz
   tar xvfz autoconf-latest.tar.gz
   cd autoconf-2.69/
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```
4. then you have to go to directory level

   ```
   cd ***YOURPHPDIRECTORY***/ext/mcrypt/
   ```

   and run phpize within this directory level

   ```
   /usr/bin/phpize
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```
5. modify your php.ini to enable the mcrypt extension by insert this into php.ini

   ```
   extension=mcrypt.so
   ```
6. Restart web server.

Answer (score 3):

**For Mac users's specially - install it using *Home Brew***

I’ve installed an empty Laravel installation and got the following error message when navigating to http://localhost/kanban/public/:

Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 – assumed ‘MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128′ in /Library/WebServer/Documents/xxx/config/app.php on line 83

Googling for this error message return many tutorials on how to install mcrypt on Mac OS X (whether building it from source or using Homebrew). The problem was that both the mcrypt and the php55-mcrypt packages were properly installed:

```
$ brew install mcrypt
Warning: mcrypt-2.6.8 already installed
$ brew install php55-mcrypt
Warning: php55-mcrypt-5.5.20 already installed
```

Mcrypt was also properly loaded by PHP:

```
$ php -m | grep mcrypt
mcrypt

$ php -i | grep mcrypt
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini,
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*
mcrypt
mcrypt support => enabled
mcrypt_filter support => enabled
mcrypt.algorithms_dir => no value => no value
mcrypt.modes_dir => no value => no value
```

for more details refer this link - http://benohead.com/mac-os-x-php-notice-use-undefined-constant-mcrypt_rijndael_128/

Comment: after all I still have this issue, any hint for mac?

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeing this on ubuntu or other flavors of *nix , it might help to do the following:

```
service php5-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I use nginx and php-fpm, and already did `apt-get install php5-mcrypt`, and moved the `mcrypt.ini` file to `mods-available`.

I had to do `sudo service php5-fpm restart` before it actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just adjusted the `.bash_profile` in MacOS and it worked:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
PHP_AUTOCONF="/usr/local/bin/autoconf"
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem in trying to deploy a `Laravel` to `Apache` on `Mac OS Sierra`. I eventually found [this post](https://jenssegers.com/49/installing-the-php-mcrypt-extension-on-osx-10-9) that gave step-by-step instructions to resolve this issue. These instructions assume that you have [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) installed; if you don't have it installed, then paste the following into a Terminal window to install it:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Here is the relevant steps pasted from the post given above:

**Step 1: Install autoconf and mcrypt**

I used homebrew to install autoconf and mcrypt, which is as easy as:

```
brew install autoconf mcrypt
```

If this does not work for you, or you don't want to use homebrew, then check out [this tutorial](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-php-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks-development-server).

**Step 2: Build the PHP extension**

To build the PHP extension you will need the PHP 5.4.17 source code that is available for download [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/archive/PHP-5.4.17.zip) and extract it:

```
cd ~/Downloads
unzip PHP-5.4.17.zip
```

Then build the extension using the following commands:

```
cd php-src-PHP-5.4.17/ext/mcrypt/
/usr/bin/phpize
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

**Step 3: Enable the extension**

All that is left is to enable the extension by editing /etc/php.ini. If this file is not present, copy /etc/php.ini.default and rename it:

```
sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```

Edit the /etc/php.ini file and add the following:

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

**Step 4: Restart apache**
Now just restart apache and you're done!

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

**ADDITIONAL NOTES AND CLARIFICATION**

I did encounter two issues with following these steps:

1. I had to match the `PHP` zip file that I downloaded to the version of PHP that was installed on my machine.

So I did

```
php -v
```

to determine the version number and then changed the download to match that version number. In my case the `PHP` version was 5.6.28 and so I needed to download the PHP source from

```
https://github.com/php/php-src/archive/PHP-5.6.28.zip
```

2. I got an exception at step 2 when I tried to do the `sudo make install`, the exception was caused by SIP, a security featured added by `El Capitan`. The exception is outlined in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208815/error-configuring-mcrypt-after-upgrading-to-el-capitan), and the resolution to this problem I found in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/236950/224105).

Applying the information from this answer changed the step 2 listed above and replaced the `sudo make install` with the following:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/php/extensions
sudo make EXTENSION_DIR='/usr/local/lib/php/extensions' install
```

Take note that because of this change, step 4 above also needs to changed to include the path to `mcrypt.so`. So the following must go in the `php.ini`:

```
extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/mcrypt.so
```

Answer (score 0):

detailed instructions here https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php
make sure you choose appropriate extension version as of your PHP version