# Mcrypt error when open up laravel

Tags: php, laravel

First of all, I would like to say that I know there are many articles about this issue but unfortunately I cannot fix it. So, I decided to ask again.

I am using mac yosemite. I follow this video to learn laravel: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/1
but I am stucked. Because I am getting error when I type localhost:8888 in my browser.

[image]

I will be so happy if we can fix this problem. Thank you.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/use-of-undefined-constant-mcrypt-rijndael-128-assumed-mcrypt-rijndael-128

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of undefined constant MCRYPT\_RIJNDAEL\_128 - assumed 'MCRYPT\_RIJNDAEL\_128'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29993399/use-of-undefined-constant-mcrypt-rijndael-128-assumed-mcrypt-rijndael-128)

Comment: @GabrielOshiro I tried that and doesn't work

Comment: @GabrielOshiro in that page he says download mycript then configure make and install it. but I don't know how to configure it?

Comment: @cyonder Do you run your own server?

Comment: @Machavity no this is on mac. I installed apache and php on my mac

Comment: First you should use Homestead. You wouldn't have those issues. Secondly, installing mcrypt can be done following this http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-php-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks-development-server/