# what to do if mcyrpt not working in php 7.2 is there any solution or alternative method?

Tags: php

> Warning: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed
>   'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128' (this will throw an Error in a future version of
>   PHP) in D:\xampp\htdocs\project\PHPKit\17082017\AES.php on line 82

getting this error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of undefined constant MCRYPT\_RIJNDAEL\_128 - assumed 'MCRYPT\_RIJNDAEL\_128'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29993399/use-of-undefined-constant-mcrypt-rijndael-128-assumed-mcrypt-rijndael-128)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe need to install some dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt

sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: mcrypt is depreated in php 7.2

Comment: You can install it by dev

Comment: what do you mean with "by dev"?

Comment: Downloading the lib from the repositorie, because a lot of code of enterprise software need that feature.

Comment: my php version is 7.4.